# Puppeteer CPU 100% server kills the process

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

I need to run as many browsers as we can but once CPU goes to 100% for some secs aws server is killing the scrapper process. Is there a way to limit cpu use to maybe 95 so the process does not get removed?

params I tried:

```
const options = {
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
      '--no-first-run',
      '--no-zygote',
      '--single-process', // <- this one doesn't works in Windows
      '--disable-gpu'
    ],
    headless: true
  }

  return await puppeteer.launch(options)
```

I need to be able to launch N browsers to scrape but never hit the 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when a server `CPU` is floored at `100%` usage, you will experience lockups, very slow processes, time-outs, and just unpredictable things. It isn't unheard-of for servers to be running at `100% CPU` usage--as [some software and programs out there have been designed to run at that percentage](https://serverfault.com/a/1032778/440254).

There probably is some AWS tiers out there where they send out e-mails trying to ask to restart your machine if the `CPU` has been `100%` for `X amount of hours`. Hopefully that isn't happening with your plan/service.

When a server is `OOM` (out-of-<strike>mana</strike>**`memory`**) or `RAM` is at `100%`, that is when the `OS` will start killing processes. The order in which it may kill the process is usually based off a `priority`, `execution time`, or a secret algorithm no one could understand.

1. There is not going to be a way to limit `CPU` use to an arbitrary number below `100%` using the `puppeteer.launch()` options/args.
   At least not as far as I have ever seen.
2. Test your code for performance problems.
   There are [several ways to troubleshoot your program/code to ensure that it isn't your own program that is causing the problem](https://medium.com/geekculture/dealing-with-node-js-high-cpu-in-production-71c432d8bece). `Puppeteer` + `JavaScript` in general makes it easy for a memory leak to occur which could be a huge issue. Multiple large loops over a [Promise with an Array of ElementHandles (page.$$)](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.__#remarks) can be a huge performance killer.
3. Failing to close a `fs (file stream)` or `browsers` & `pages` can add up eventually too. Lucky for us, we have `Garbage Collection` to come and try to fix the problem; while at the same time using more `memory`/`CPU`.
4. ###### Use Kubernets with a Puppeteer Manager to manually control your own browsers. I highly recommend taking a look at the [Digital Ocean Tutorial | Puppeteer + node.js + Kubernetes + Docker + Load Balancing](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-concurrent-web-scraper-with-puppeteer-node-js-docker-and-kubernetes#step-6-mdash-deploying-the-scraper-to-kubernetes) about using a variety of tools to make scraping a very organized and abstract process. Assuming you haven't already seen it or have used it.
5. `Kubernetes` + `Docker` + `Load Balancing` can all be done on `AWS` too. Adding in tools like `Kubernetes` + `Docker` brings huge functionality for monitoring resources. An example would be: pausing a container and restarting it on a different balancer. Plus many other things that are too specific for this answer.
6. Lastly, I think the best way to keep your browsers stable is to monitor your server and identify how many browsers you can run before it starts getting towards the `OOM` / `100% RAM` usage. Not worry as much about the `100% CPU` limit, unless it is significantly impacting performance.

###### Hope this helps or adds some insight into your question.